# How to set relative file path in include controller of Jmeter?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0, jmeter-maven-plugin

I am trying to call a Test fragment which consists of reusable sampler. I want to call the test fragment in my other script using Include controller, I want to achieve this by giving relative path in include controller, It is working when absolute path of the test fragment is set but gives an error if provided with relative path.

**Below path I have set in user defined variable: (folder structure is based on Maven project)**

../../../src/test/resources/testData

Below is the error which I get:
[image]

**Below is the path I have set in user defined variable config for Test Fragment:**
[image]

**Below is the image of Include controller in which i am trying to call the test fragment using relative/dynamic path:**
[image]

Comment: Do you try remove space in `Login TestFragment.jmx`?

Comment: Yes, it is the same file name which I gave earlier, Now I have the file name in proper camel case but still facing the issue.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Include Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Include_Controller) documentation:

> This element d**oes not support variables/functions in the filename** field.
>
> However, if the property `includecontroller.prefix` is defined, the contents are used to prefix the pathname.

So you have the following workarounds:

1. Consider embedding the external .jmx file into the main one using [Module Controller](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421345-Using-JMeter-Module-Controller-Using-JMeter-Module-Controller)
2. Or run your "included" script as a separate process using [OS Process Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#OS_Process_Sampler), the .jtl results file can be combined with the "parent" result file via [Merge Results](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/MergeResults/) tool

Answer (score 0):

### TLDR;

**ForEach Controller**(testFragmentName) -> **Switch Controller**(testFragmentName) -> [**IncludeController1**(existingPath1),**IncludeController2**(existingPath2)]

## Intro & my data

So... I've been researching the subject and didn't like any proposed solutions as I want to have full control of the project.

My idea is to have suites defined in json like:

```
{
    "Suites": [
        {
            "name": "ExampleTest",
            "testFragments": [
                "Login",
                "HomePage",
                "Logout"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Having defined the test and it's modules I go to selected test plan.

## Test plan elements, main points

Used HTTP Request with file protocol to get json file with data to extract:
[image]

**Property/variable input:** suites
**Json Path:** `$.Suites[?(@.name in [${suites}])].testFragments.*`

Now I prepare such test structure:
**| ForEach

| - Switch

| - - Include1

| - - Include2

...**

**ForEach Controller**
[image: ForEach]
**Switch Controller**
[image: Switch]

**Include Controllers**
The only thing left to do is define every Include Controller with existing path name so error doesn't occure. I don't suggest using `includecontroller.prefix` as it's pretty much useless.

The whole operation requires defining all external jmx test fragments within the switch controller as Include Controllers with correct names (switch controllers needs to know which controller to chose).

## Conclusion

In my opinion it's worth as you can use external properties ('suites' or other as you would like) to run predefined suites.

It's not perfect but it allows complete modularization and external control via simple property input.

*`PS. Include Controller is obviously a strong contender for the worst design of functionality ever.`*